# Node.JS Downloading files to Telegram directly using a bot

Tags: node.js, telegram, telegram-bot, telegraf

I'm using Telegraf library with Node.JS to create a bot to upload files and generate a download link
everything is fine but when I click the link it will open in the browser
I want the media to be downloaded directly inside the bot

```
    bot.on('message', async ctx => {

    if(ctx.update.message.photo) {
        let link = await bot.telegram.getFileLink(ctx.message.photo[ctx.message.photo.length - 1].file_id)
        bot.telegram.sendMessage(
            ctx.chat.id,
            `<a href = "${link}"> Download Photo </a>`,
            { parse_mode : 'html' }
        )
    }
```

this code gives me a download link which will opens in browser and I don't want that , the thing i want is to download the file directly inside the chat section like when someone sending you a file

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you send the photo as a document/file. So users can download it within Telegram.

You need to change:

```
bot.telegram.sendMessage(
  ctx.chat.id,
  `<a href = "${link}"> Download Photo </a>`,
  { parse_mode : 'html' }
)
```

to:

```
bot.telegram.sendDocument(
  ctx.chat.id,
  link
)
```